# How to program a "decimal HTML decoder"?

Tags: r, html-encode

I wish to create (in the R language) a "decimal HTML decoder" such as the one implemented in this website:

http://www.hashemian.com/tools/html-url-encode-decode.php

But I'm not sure where to start, could someone propose any pointers on what to read/which translation table (or formula) to use?

My original motivation for this will be the decoding of Hebrew characters.  (for example, the translation of something like this:

```
&#x5E9;&#x5DC;&#x5D5;&#x5DD;
```

To this:

```
שלום
```

)

(hat tip goes to Matt Shotwell for the pointers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inp <- "&#x5E9;&#x5DC;&#x5D5;&#x5DD;"
nohash <- sub("#", "0", strsplit(inp, "&")[[1]])  # cvrt # to 0
nohash
# [1] ""       "0x5E9;" "0x5DC;" "0x5D5;" "0x5DD;"
strtoi( sub(";", "", nohash) )  # remove trailing ";" and cvrt to dec
# [1]    0 1513 1500 1493 1501
```

Edit the time has expired on adding to my comment so I'll add this link that seems to have a [conversion table](http://czyborra.com/charsets/iso8859.html#ISO-8859-8):

Comment: Hello again DWin :)  Thanks for this part.  Do you know where there is a translation table between the numbers extracted, to the proper Hebrew characters? (what should be searched in google for this?)

Comment: I have enough problem keeping my Engrish and R straight ... but I'll try... see if this works: http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/hebrew.html  Used the search string "html encoding hebrew text". Another site suggested these character sets: Hebrew (DOS)
    ##charset=DOS-862 
Hebrew (ISO-Logical)
    ##charset=iso-8859-8-i 
Hebrew (ISO-Visual)
    ##charset=iso-8859-8 
Hebrew (Mac)
    ##charset=x-mac-hebrew 
Hebrew (Windows)
    ##charset=windows-1255